# Word search function within the page (Ctrl+F function web implementation)

Tags: javascript

Using the code below, you can search for a word within a page.
But what if you want to search only in a specified area ("div id" or "div class")?

I am a beginner.

The code is said to be long.
See codepen.

https://codepen.io/spviyyta/pen/bGWdjzM

```js
var TRange = null

function findString(str) {
  if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) < 4) return;
  var strFound;
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {

    // NAVIGATOR-SPECIFIC CODE

    strFound = self.find(str);
    if (!strFound) {
      strFound = self.find(str, 0, 1)
      while (self.find(str, 0, 1)) continue
    }
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {

    // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

    if (TRange != null) {
      TRange.collapse(false)
      strFound = TRange.findText(str)
      if (strFound) TRange.select()
    }
    if (TRange == null || strFound == 0) {
      TRange = self.document.body.createTextRange()
      strFound = TRange.findText(str)
      if (strFound) TRange.select()
    }
  }
  if (!strFound) alert("검색어 '" + str + "'을[를] 찾을 수 없습니다. 띄어쓰기를 정확하게 해주세요.")
}
```

```html
test text 텍스트 텍스트
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <form name="f1" action="" onSubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='')
  findString(this.t1.value);return false">
    <input type="text" name=t1 value="" size=20 style=" background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;">

    <input type="submit" name=b1 value="찾기" style="  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;">
  </form>
</div>
test text 텍스트 텍스트
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant example text and post the findString

Comment: Pleasde update the snippet with the divs you want to search

Comment: i solved .  https://codepen.io/spviyyta/pen/NWjXJeP

Answer (score 0):

Not trivial

Here I can highlight the node that contains the value entered

More code is needed to only select the value

```js
const div = document.getElementById("searchDiv");
document.getElementById("f1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();

  const val = this.t1.value.trim();
  if (val === "") return;


  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(div);
  selection.addRange(range);
  [...div.childNodes].forEach((node, i) => {
    console.log(val, i, node.textContent)
    if (node.textContent.includes(val)) {
      startOffset = i;
      const endOffset = i + 1
      range.setStart(div, startOffset);
      range.setEnd(div, endOffset);
      const mark = document.createElement('mark');
      range.surroundContents(mark);

    }
  });
})
```

```css
.inp {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.sub {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="f1" action="">
    <input type="text" name=t1 value="" size=20 class="inp" />
    <input type="submit" name=b1 value="찾기" class="sub" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="searchDiv">
  <p>test text</p>
  <p> 텍스트 텍스트</p>
</div>

<div id="ignoreDiv">
  test text 텍스트 텍스트
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.getElementById("searchDiv");
document.getElementById("f1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();

  const val = this.t1.value.trim();
  if (val === "") return;


  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(div);
  selection.addRange(range);
  [...div.childNodes].forEach((node, i) => {
    console.log(val, i, node.textContent)
    if (node.textContent.includes(val)) {
      startOffset = i;
      const endOffset = i + 1
      range.setStart(div, startOffset);
      range.setEnd(div, endOffset);
      const mark = document.createElement('mark');
      range.surroundContents(mark);

    }
  });
})
```

```css
.inp {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.sub {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="f1" action="">
    <input type="text" name=t1 value="" size=20 class="inp" />
    <input type="submit" name=b1 value="찾기" class="sub" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="searchDiv">
  <p>test text</p>
  <p> 텍스트 텍스트</p>
</div>

<div id="ignoreDiv">
  test text 텍스트 텍스트
</div>
```